# Como agregar un condicional IF a un componente de renderizado en el cual hago dos .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy teniendo un problema constante al intentar renderizar el detalle de un producto en particular.
Lo que sucede es que cuando intento agregar un segundo if que compare el id recibido por el path de la ruta usando el hook useParams la aplicacion se rompe completamente.
Ademas tambien tengo un problema que en por mas que este en la misma ruta el componente rompe las imagenes.
Adjunto codigo del componente

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ItemDetailsContainer(props) {
    const [idCategory, setIdCategory] = useState("");
    const [idItem, setIdItem] = useState("");
    const param = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.products) {
            props.products.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.category === param.item) {
                    setIdCategory(element.id);
                }
            });
        }
        setIdItem(param.id)
    }, [param]);

    return (
        <div className="contenedor-details">
            {

                props.products.map((element) => {
                    if (element.id === idCategory) {
                        return (
                            element.items.map(items => (
                                
                                        <div>
                                            <img src={items.img} className='imgs-card' />
                                            <div className="informacion">
                                                <p>{items.nameProduct}</p>
                                                <p className="precio">{items.price}<span>.99</span></p>
                                                <button>Comprar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                            )
                    }
                })
            }
        </div>
    )


}
```

Necesito unicamente renderizar el componente donde la ruta y la categoria coinicidan con el path del useParams.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

---

Comment: A que te refieres con que se rompe? hay mensajes de error? compartelos

Comment: No hay un mensaje de error, el componente no se renderiza. Asi como esta unicamente renderiza las cards correspondientes a la categoria. Yo necesito que renderice un card en particular.

Comment: Verifica que ese `element.id` tenga valores en el array `items`, si no hay errores puede que ese array `items` este vacio.

Comment: El elemnt.id tiene datos, ya que los recibe por props products que es un objeto, con los datos. Lo chequie con el console.log

Comment: `console.log(element.items.length)` verifica esto, que salida tiene?

Comment: Hola, eso arroja 4 que es el tamaño del árray de items dentro del element, en este caso products.

Comment: Aclaro nuevamente que lo que necesitaria es agregar la siguiente linea de codigo para renderizar unicamente una card: if(items.idProduct === idItem). El inconveniente surge cuando esté condicional se coloca posterior al map de items, esto genera que no se renderice. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Solucionado, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Hola Agustin, me alegro de que encontrarás la solución, ahora bien, podrías editar tu pregunta, quitar la solución de ella, y agregarla en la zona de respuestas?, asi evitarás recibir votos negativos y ayudarás a otros que tengan el mismo problema, gracias, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Listo, gracias por la informacion! ya lo modifique. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo solucionado para todo aquel que tenga el mismo problema. Lo soluciono chatgpt con el siguiente codigo:

return (    
{

```
        props.products.map((element) => {
          
            if (element.id === idCategory) {

                return (
                    element.items.map(items => {
                        
                        if (items.idProduct == idItem) {
                            console.log(element.items.idProduct)
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <img src={items.img} className='imgs-card' />
                                    <div className="informacion-details">
                                        <p>{items.nameProduct}</p>
                                        <p>{items.description}</p>
                                        <p className="precio-details">{items.price}<span>.99</span></p>
                                        <button>Comprar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        } 
                    })
                )
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        })
    }
</div>
```

)